# Array index out of bounds: index0

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following code:

```
public interface CustomPlanRepository {
    void plansUpdate(Query query,Update update,Class classname,String Collection);  
}

@Repository
public interface PlanRepository extends MongoRepository<Plan, 
                                          Serializable>,CustomPlanRepository{

    Plan findById(String id);
}
```

it throws the following exception during server startup:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error  creating bean with name 'planManagementController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency  expressed through field 'planService'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating  bean with name 'planServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field  'planRepository'; nested exception
>   is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean  with name 'planRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception  is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Index: 0

If I remove this:

```
void plansUpdate(Query query,Update update,Class classname,String Collection);
```

the server loads perfectly fine.

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you implements PlanRepository (PlanRepositoryImpl), can you post the code ?

Comment: Does CustomPlanRepository have Repository and extends some Mango or other repository? Or do you have your own implementation for it? Post that info

Comment: I autowired PlanRepository in my service class@ Mr_THORYNQUE

Answer (score 0):

When you combine MongoRepository and a customRepository (CustomPlanRepository) you have to implements CustomRepository interface (CustomPlanRepositoryImpl). Spring can't create this implementation.

```
public class CustomPlanRepositoryImpl implements CustomPlanRepository {
    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

     void plansUpdate(Query query,Update update,Class classname,String Collection){
    ....

     }
```

Comment: Don't change your final autowired with PlanReposity interface.